# Averaging JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, mqtt, node-red

I have an environmental sensor sending values via mqtt to node red.  the sensor values can vary so im attempting to average the last few to smooth out the reading a little.  However I'm not getting the output that I'm expecting.  The values that are being input (msg.payload) are ranging from '9865' to '10008'  .  I would expect the output to be ~5.9 but I'm getting decimal places i.e. '0.5766570605187319'

```js
var calSolution1 = 7.00;
var calSolution2 = 4.00;
var calReading1 = 9564;
var calReading2 = 10605;

var length = 10;
var phArray = new Array(length);

var m = (calSolution2-calSolution1)/(calReading2-calReading1); //slope
var b = calSolution1-m*calReading1; //intercept
var x = msg.payload;

var pH = m*x+b;

  phArray.shift();
  phArray.push(pH);


const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
msg.payload = (phArray.reduce(reducer) / length);

return msg;
```

Comment: Why are you using an array if you only put one element into it? From the code you provided, I guess it would be the same as `msg.payload = (m*x+b)/length`

Comment: a new msg.payload is being received every 10 seconds.  I would like to average the last 10 to smooth out the variation in readings.

Answer (score 1):

`phArray` has a length 10, but before it's been filled, like when the first message is being processed, it has a single valid element:

```
phArray = [<empty> ...x9, 5]
```

When this is `reduce`d only the `5` is taken into account, so the average is `5`, which is divided by `10`. The calculation is wrong because of the technically-correct-but-logically-wrong `length`.

It'd be cleaner to use a real circular buffer/array implementation—they keep track of their logical length for you (or roll your own). Since its `length` property is logically consistent it can be used for taking the average.

---

Unrelated, but when a snippet isn't executable, there's no point in it being a snippet. This could be prototyped with a source value array that's iterated over, running your data processing code at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Node-RED have you looked at [node-red-node-smooth](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-smooth)?

It can be configured to provide an average of a given number of values.